# Increment non-existent variable in php loop

Tags: php, loops, variables

I have a foreach loop, inside of which I am building a big multi-dimensional array and doing lots of incriminating, like this:

```
$totalCosts['sawn']['materials'] += $sawnMaterialsCost;
```

On the first iteration of the loop, the key 'materials' is not set, so it throws an undefined index notice (not terrible, but annoying).

I can fix that by defining it before the loop like this:

```
$totalCosts['sawn']['materials'] = '0.00';
```

BUT, I have many keys I am filling by incrementing, and I don't like having to set each variable/key to '0' for every one before looping. Is there a better way to do this so the first iteration of the loop checks for a value and sets it to 1 if not found?

Comment: it is better to show full fragment of code with your loop. And  you can not set up numeric value to `'0.00'` it should be just `0`

Comment: As it seems to be dealing with money, I strongly encourage you to use bcmath as you may never find exact result otherwise due to the base 10 base 2 conversion implied by native php operators

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$totalCosts['sawn']['materials'] = ($totalCosts['sawn']['materials'] ?? 0) + $sawnMaterialsCost;
```

[`??`](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op), an operator introduced in PHP 7, uses the left-hand operand if defined and not null, otherwise the right-hand operand.

The performance cost of `??` is negligible, unless you are doing millions of comparisons. On an Amazon c3.medium, I measured each at ~250ns more than a static assignment. On a loop of 10,000,000 that's a half-second penalty.

[perf.code.](https://3v4l.org/o93Mb)

Comment: null coalescing operator to the rescue! I thought there might be a solution using this, but I was trying to use it in the wrong place.

Comment: imho it has nothing to do with the question posted

Comment: You're right, sorry, this is dealing with the wrong side of the variable, I spoke too soon. It's the $totalCosts keys that are unset on the first iteration, not the sawnMaterialsCost variable.

Comment: Excellent, thanks. @user3783243 Running Wordpress on a 7.0+ server and this plugin is not for distro, so I should be OK in this case.

Comment: While this code is correct, the fact this code is needed at all is **HUGE** code bloat to the script.

Answer (score 1):

Yes - first check if it exists, and if not, create it.

```
foreach($something as $key) { //e.g. $key = 'materials'
    if (!isset($totalCosts['sawn'][$key])) $totalCosts['sawn'][$key] = 0;
    $totalCosts['sawn'][$key] += $sawnMaterialsCost;
}
```

Comment: No, thank you :) Not in a 2000 lines code that will become a 3000 lines code :(

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't think there is a solution way more compact than this:

```
foreach(...) {
    if(!isset($totalCosts['sawn'][$yourkey]))
       $totalCosts['sawn'][$yourkey] = 0.00;
    $totalCosts['sawn'][$yourkey]+=$sawnMaterialsCost;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the ternary operator is one way you can accomplish this.

```
$totalCosts['sawn']['materials'] = !empty($totalCosts['sawn']['materials']) ? $totalCosts['sawn']['materials'] + $sawnMaterialsCost : $sawnMaterialsCost;
```

This way you won't try adding to a non-existent value.

Comment: I like this because it's sort of "one line" but still long. Might be the shortest way though.